# Miscellaneous wire from Compaq CQ70 laptop display

Tags: laptop, display, compaq-laptop

Could anyone tell me what this wire is for? The one that ends in a small clear plastic rectangle. I'm not sure if it's supposed to connect to somewhere on the motherboard or if it's an antenna or something.

[Compaq CQ70 display wire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j34DF.jpg)

UPDATE: After looking at the service manual mentioned in the comments below, it appears to be the caps lock LED wire.

Comment: Sure looks an LED light bulb. All of these old Compaqs have service manuals available online, have you tried pulling and looking at the screen replacement instructions? Might give some clues.

Comment: Ahh, that makes sense. What would that LED indicate? I can't work out where it goes. EDIT: No, but I'll have a search now.

Comment: FWIW.. Here is a complete disassembly video. Look around 11:00 to the end of the video, complete disassembly of screen unit. Looks like it's part of the backllighting. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2K_8VFDzSI4

Comment: And here is the service manual http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01573159

Comment: Thanks! It looks like it's the caps lock LED, which is a bit of a surprise.